# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Auto Deployment of MF Application on remote MF Server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to deploy my Mobile First Application which is on my local machine into Mobile first Server which on remote machine (VM).

I'm following this [Article](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/moving-production/moving-development-environment-stand-alone-qa-production-servers/). I configured everything (.war,.wlapp and .adapter) on remote server using Server Configuration Tool and Mobile First Console.I mean, I created a new runtime environment in Server Configuration Tool and I added .wlapp and .adater files in Mobile First Console.

I have a doubt at 3rd Step in this document  **The application server configuration file can be edited with additional MobileFirst properties.** How can I edit Mobile First properties file.

Now I have done some changes on application and then I'm running application like this  **Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target**. In this I'm giving my remote server details. But the changes are not happening on my server.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have done some changes on application and then I'm running
>   application like this Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target. In
>   this I'm giving my remote server details. But the changes are not
>   happening on my server.

This was fixed as part of APAR *PI48848 INCORRECT SERVER HOST IS WRITTEN IN WORKLIGHT.PLIST/WLCLIENT.PRO PERTIES, IF SERVERHOST IS DIFFERENT THAN LOCALHOST*, where the host value that was set in the Build Setting and Remote Target dialog was not inserted into the generated wlclient.properties file of the native project.

To receive the fix, download and install the latest Studio iFix available in IBM Fix Central.